# Could I use the foot pedal of an electric sewing machine to control the speed of rotary tools?

Tags: dimmer

I am searching for a solution for powering power tools with lower noise levels.  I live in an apartment and have many neighbors around me.  When I have little projects,  I don't want to disturb my neighbors. For example when I have to use the angle grinder it would be enough for me to use it half the speed or the hand planer as well.

I have the pedal of an electric sewing machine laying around so I thought about using it as a speed controller for the tool.

Would it work exactly like a commercially bought variac/ light dimmer? When not, what would be the difference?

Is this plausible and possible?

Comment: The tools in question probably exceed the rating of a sewing machine pedal, either a traditional resistive one or a triac.  But a sewing machine pedal is indeed pretty much interchangeable with the control for a light duty rotary tool such as a "dremel".  Also, questions on the *usage* of products are not on topic here, and doubly so when specification are missing.

Comment: Even with a speed control of appropriate rating the *effectiveness* of your tools is likely to be drastically reduced when operated below the designed speed, not just because the motor will have less power, but because the cutting operation itself has a suitable speed range and the quality of results is poor both above *and below* that ideal speed.  If you look you'll find tables of the ideal cutting speed (typically in surface feet/minute, though metric countries may use something else) for cutting and grinding various materials.

Comment: Generally the handheld version of tools with universal motors are the noisiest, while fixed machinery of heavy cast iron construction with an induction motor can be far quieter, however the high cutting speeds of woodworking often making it inherently louder than metalworking.

Comment: It is definetly the noise of the powertools making noise independent of the working progress. Idling an angle grinder or a hand planer will give everybody an idea of the noise level of "just" an electric motor.

Comment: That idle noise is due to the brushed universal motor, lightweight construction, and any gearbox.  Fixed tools with heavy cast iron frames, induction motors, and belt drive are quite quiet until they start cutting.  In theory, lightweight tools with brushless motors could be made which would be quiet when merely spinning... but there's probably not a market demand, and they'd still be loud when they cut wood.  Slowing down what you have is going to be disappointing, if you want quiet, you might consider the unpowered *hand* tools.

Comment: Many power tools have built-in fans to cool their motors and gears. If run at half speed the cooling may not be sufficiently effective, leading to shorter life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible, assuming that the items mentioned all have universal motors and it seems likely that they would. You would need to check the current or power rating of the pedal controller. If it is not marked on the controller, you will need to determine what sewing machines they are for and check the machines. If you exceed the current or power rating, they are likely to overheat and fail pretty quickly.

The controller is probably similar to the subject of [How does this circuit control motor speed?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296059/how-does-this-circuit-control-motor-speed) That question includes a diagram showing that the motor current flows through an inductor, a triac and an unknown component that might be a thermal fuse. To upgrade the controller, all three of those components would need to be changed. The traic may also need a heatsink.

Comment: Which component is likely to fail first within the pedal because of the high power handling. Maybe i could upgrade this component within the pedal to last a little bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the pedal. Sometimes the pedal only contains a potentiometre to sense the pedal position. The power electronics can then be inside the sewing machine. Also the pedal may not directly control any power electronics, but there might be a microprocessor to read the pedal position and the microprocessor then controls the power electronics.

Comment: Sometimes the pedal just presses two lumps of carbon together with increasing pressure...

Comment: Or a simple rheostat in series with the motor. My grandfather converted my mother's 110 V sewing machine to 220 V in the 1960s by adding a lightbulb in series. It would glow brighter with increased pedal pressure or increased motor load. Simple times!